# Application crashes after first launch

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

I already have this app on app store. I released an updated version with some changes. This app is using CoreData for data persistence. I have tested its new version before releasing it on app store, it was working as required. But after submitting on app store and updating it from there the app is crashing after each launch. I have that crash report, but it doesn't make any sense to me. I didn't change anything in CoreData.
After launch, this app is showing a UITableView and this tableView is getting data from CoreData.

Here is the crash report.

```
Incident Identifier: 7A9713FF-40CB-45E0-961F-F4D1B003F2B5
CrashReporter Key:   891c38a57639ab8e2bcc3012687292ce9aa818f5
Hardware Model:      iPhone6,2
Process:             APPName [7461]
Path:                /var/mobile/Applications/A9028B70-0878-40FA-944B-584B15E49B69/APPName.app/APPName
Identifier:          co.identifier.app
Version:             2.5 (2.5)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2014-03-13 09:39:17.309 +0000
OS Version:          iOS 7.0.6 (11B651)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d
Highlighted Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
co.identifier.app failed to launch in time

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 1.660 (user 1.660, system 0.000), 4% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.304, 1% CPU

Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a161fa8 __psynch_mutexwait + 24
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a1c6f4d _pthread_mutex_lock + 305
2   CoreData                        0x2f595a91 -[_PFLock lock] + 21
3   CoreData                        0x2f5a6b35 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 777
4   CoreData                        0x2f5a5777 -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] + 611
5   APPName                         0x000ecc11 +[DataManager dataEntryEntity:] (DataManager.m:385)
6   APPName                         0x000ebca9 +[DataManager dataForDateKey:] (DataManager.m:126)
7   APPName                         0x000cff9d -[CalendarCell setDateKey:] (CalendarCell.m:820)
8   APPName                         0x000bd969 -[CalendarViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] (CalendarViewController.m:832)
9   UIKit                           0x32108311 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 405
10  UIKit                           0x320b06c9 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 1797
11  UIKit                           0x320afeed -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 181
12  UIKit                           0x31fd634f -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 343
13  QuartzCore                      0x31c5c93f -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 139
14  QuartzCore                      0x31c58163 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 347
15  QuartzCore                      0x31c57ff5 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 13
16  QuartzCore                      0x31c57a09 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 225
17  QuartzCore                      0x31c5781b CA::Transaction::commit() + 311
18  UIKit                           0x32055a37 -[UIApplication _reportAppLaunchFinished] + 39
19  UIKit                           0x32040edb -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 1643
20  UIKit                           0x31fdba03 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3139
21  UIKit                           0x31fdacf9 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 69
22  UIKit                           0x3204031d _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 661
23  GraphicsServices                0x344ba76b _PurpleEventCallback + 607
24  GraphicsServices                0x344ba353 PurpleEventCallback + 31
25  CoreFoundation                  0x2f81c775 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 33
26  CoreFoundation                  0x2f81c70f __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 343
27  CoreFoundation                  0x2f81aedb __CFRunLoopRun + 1403
28  CoreFoundation                  0x2f78546d CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 521
29  CoreFoundation                  0x2f78524f CFRunLoopRunInMode + 103
30  UIKit                           0x3203f5bf -[UIApplication _run] + 759
31  UIKit                           0x3203a841 UIApplicationMain + 1133
32  APPName                         0x000b6ba7 main (main.m:11)
33  libdyld.dylib                   0x3a0abab5 start + 1
```

This crash is producing on every device which updates the app and this is not reproducing in simulator testing or in testing build through testFlight distribution.

Comment: Did you change the data model? If so, this will be your cause.

Comment: It's complaining about the amount of time that you're taking before launch is complete.  Since the main thread is waiting on a lock, my first question is: Is some other thread holding that lock and blocking you?  (The other possibility is that you're just doing too much work when you populate your table cells and need to move some of it into the background.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From  http://www.raywenderlich.com/23704/demystifying-ios-application-crash-logs

Here are some of the more common exception codes:
0x8badf00d: Reads as “ate bad food”! (If you squint your eyes and replace the digits with alphabetic characters. :p) This code indicates that an application was terminated by iOS because a watchdog timeout occurred. Basically, the application took too long to launch, terminate, or respond to system events.

The crash is because of a long wait, what's causing it is in 1 of 321 task items listed in the log.

I am really curious about your send event / handle event items in the log. Is there any chance that you are waiting for something before launching the rootViewController?    ... it could be core data but if there is something very wrong I sort of expected another error to happen instead of along wait.

Comment: You are right there was something which was blocking main thread. But I am not sure it will stop the crashing issue or not. Will test it. Thanks for the clue.

Answer (score 1):

As Phillip stated in the comment, the reason for this crash is due to the watchdog.
If your app is stuck in the method `-applicationDidFinishLauchingWithOptions:` for a long time, the system kills it.
The reason is that probably you are doing an expensive time task on the main thread inside this method, that could be a migration, copying or deleting a lot of files.
You never experienced in your tests because probably you used small amount of data or because in debug mode the watchdog isn't active (not sure about it).
Unfortunately I think that you should release another version as soon as possible to fix that, the solution could be launch those long running task on a background thread.
To prevent those problems always to try updating an old app using ad-hoc distribution before releasing it.

Comment: I did test it before releasing it to app store. But this was totally unexpected case for me. Any how are you aware of any method in which you can distribute your app to any user.? Right now I am aware of those methods in which you add UDIDs first and then only those devices can install the app.

Comment: AD-HOC distribution, requires UDIDs but is a release build instead of debug. I usually follow those steps https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/Documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html you can find also easier tutorial search on google

Comment: I as follow these guide lines. I want to get rid of adding UDIDs. Thanks @Andrea